# Only one choice for authentication in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus, google-oauth, facebook-authentication, google-openid

In my new web application, I want to authenticate users by letting them sign in with their Google, Yahoo, Facebook, or LinkedIn accounts.  Does App Engine's "Google+ Sign-In" capability allow this?  If not, is there another platform (e.g. Heroku) that would let me write straightforward code that will accomplish this?

BACKGROUND:  I can find nothing in the Google+ Sign-In documentation that talks about authenticating with any site other than Google.

However, various pages ([this one](https://developers.google.com/+/case-studies/guardian) and [this one](https://developers.google.com/+/)) show a Google+ Sign-In screen that also has a "Sign In With Facebook" button in screenshots, but it's not clear if this Facebook button is supported by App Engine's Google+ Sign-In API, or was hand-rolled with OAuth2.  Same with the "Sign In With Twitter" button.

I believe that, even if OpenID Connect were available, neither Facebook nor Twitter would participate -- except that OpenID Connect is built on OAuth2, which would allow them to participate.  However, App Engine has deprecated OAuth2 (see [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#oauth2login)).  So I am pretty confused about what is possible and what is not.

Comment: You might also look at the [Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/).

Comment: This looks like it could work!  I'm still researching what its underlying technology is.  But Google says it works on App Engine, which makes sense because it is a pure Python library: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/identitytoolkit/v3  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To support multiple authentication services (e.g. Google, Twitter, FB..) you should go with OAuth2.

One such library that works with GAE (for Java) is [pac4j](https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j). It lets you authenticate and access users profiles.

Comment: OAuth2 would seem to be a viable alternative, except that Google says they are deprecating it on App Engine (link provided in original question).  Hence my confusion.

Comment: The link about deprecation has nothing to do with AppEngine. It just says that Google+ access should be done via their new (OAuth2 based) Google+ Sign-In. Also the existing OAuth 2.0 still works, you just need to update endpoints and scope urls.